# Rails 4 Validate nested create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I've got a nested form:

```
= form_for @class4, url: {action: "create"}  do |f|
= render 'shared/error_messages' 
  .form-group
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description

  = f.fields_for :class3 do |builder|
    = render :partial => '/shared/class3', :locals => {:f => builder}
  = submit_tag( "submit") 
  = link_to 'clear'
```

with an error partial

```
<% if @instance.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    The form contains <%= pluralize(instance.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
      <% instance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

and in my controller the following code:

```
current_user
        .class1.find( params [:"id"])
        .class2.where( id: params [:"id2"])
          .first_or_create!
        .class3.where(id: params[:"id3"])
          .first_or_create!
          .class4.create!(params[:"...."])
```

The problem is, when params [:"id"] is not a valid Class1 record ID, I got an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error, which is obvious, but, I'd like to show the error to the user, just like any other form validation error, for example:

> params["ID"] is not a valid Class1 record

How can I keep the nested create while notifying the user that the ID they chose is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Add a rescue block with it like this:

```
.class1.find( params [:"id"]) rescue "params["ID"] is not a valid Class1 record"
```

This will show this message instead of throwing any error.